# NoClassDefFoundError: Changes in project import from sdk rev 15 to sdk rev 17?

Tags: android, eclipse, configuration, sdk, project

I wanted to move my projects in eclipse from SDK rev 15 to rev 17 but now I cannot run simple project import examples anymore which have no problem under rev 15. Under rev 15 I just import the project using the build path and this works fine.

With rev 17 I get the following error:

03-23 14:46:20.202: E/AndroidRuntime(323): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.simple.SimpleClassForTest

The missing class is a class from the project I try to import.

Any help is very welcome.

regards, wnck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going to the "Java Build Path" screen of the project properties.

Open the "Order and Export" tab

Ensure the box is checked next to the project that contains the class that is being reported as missing.

Comment: Yessss, this helps! An additional "Project clean" was needed but now it works. Thanks a lot!